# How to build gstreamer project using MinGW?

Tags: c, mingw, gstreamer, glib, gobject

I've installed the following two `msi` on my Windows 7 (basic) 64-bit — I downloaded the msi from [here](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows).

- `gstreamer-sdk-devel-x86_64-2013.6.msi`
- `gstreamer-sdk-x86_64-2013.6.msi`

Now I'm trying to build [this hello world](http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735) program using MinGW (GCC 4.8.1) and the linker is giving me trouble, saying this:

```
C:\Users\Apelles\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwLMXuu.o: In function `gst_message_unref':
C:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/gstmessage.h:347: undefined reference to `gst_mini_object_unref'
C:\Users\Apelles\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwLMXuu.o: In function `main':
F:\projects\gstreamer/helloworld.c:9: undefined reference to `gst_init'
F:\projects\gstreamer/helloworld.c:12: undefined reference to `gst_parse_launch'
F:\projects\gstreamer/helloworld.c:15: undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
F:\projects\gstreamer/helloworld.c:18: undefined reference to `gst_element_get_bus'
F:\projects\gstreamer/helloworld.c:19: undefined reference to `gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered'
F:\projects\gstreamer/helloworld.c:24: undefined reference to `gst_object_unref'
F:\projects\gstreamer/helloworld.c:25: undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
F:\projects\gstreamer/helloworld.c:26: undefined reference to `gst_object_unref'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which lib(s) am I missing?

Here are options which I used to build the project (taken from my `make` output):

> gcc helloworld.c -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -ansi -std=c99 -Wno-unused-parameter -mms-bitfields -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/cairo -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/pixman-1 -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/fontconfig -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/freetype2 -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/libpng15   -mms-bitfields -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/gstreamer-0.10 -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/include/libxml2    -LC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl   -LC:/gstreamer-sdk/0.10/x86_64/lib -lgstinterfaces-0.10 -lgstreamer-0.10 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lxml2 -lglib-2.0 -lintl

What is lacking in this?

What should I do in order to resolve this?

Comment: probably gstreamer itself, since `gst_init` isn't available.

Comment: @MarcB:  Dont the installed msi contain it? What did I not install (or missed while configuring)?

Comment: you've got `-lgstreamer-0.10` in there, but that'd only be useful if the gstreamer stuff is in the include/linker path.

Comment: @MarcB: I can guess that some *specific gstreamer stuff* is missing in the path, but I need to know *what* that specific thing is?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your are using MinGW's default GCC compiler which targets the x86 architecture but you have downloaded the x86_64 version of the SDK. The linker can find the libraries but I won't be able to use them.

We strongly recommend to use cerbero's build system to setup the development environment. It will take care of downloading a working toolchain and compile all the build dependencies (autotools, gettext, libtoo, pkg-config, etc...)

You will find detailed instructions [here](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Building+from+source+using+Cerbero) in the section **Build a single project with the SDK**

In short:

1. checkout cerbero's repo
2. run the bootstrap command with: *./cerbero-uninstalled -c config/win64.cbc bootstrap*
3. enter the development shell with: *./cerbero-uninstalled -c config/win64.cbc shell*